# setVisibility(GONE) view becomes invisible but still occupies space

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I've got a view that is effectively is a button. Here is its XML layout (add_new.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bText" 
        android:onClick="addNew"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I set its visibility to GONE like this

```
v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_new, null);
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

it disappears but still occupies space. Like this: [image]

This button is a header in the `ListView`, which is defined by this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/porno" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I dont want it to occupy an additional list item when its visibility is set to GONE. As it is stated in the documentation.

> GONE - This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for
>   layout purposes.

Any ideas on how to make it NOT occupy space?

Thanks,
Dennis xx

P.S. My listview is inside of a FoldersFragment `ListFragment`and here is the xml of my MainActivity where FoldersFragment is presented

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/foldersFragment"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.fragments.FoldersFragment" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.fragments.DetailFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you inflating view, just take Button.

Comment: Because I then set this view as a ListView header

Comment: please post your xml where u added the add_new.xml this is limited info!

Comment: Don't add this as Header of your List. Just take it Above the list in the XML where you have taken the list.

Comment: I want to see the XML in which you have taken the list.

Comment: Because I need that button disappear sometimes and reappear the other times. I am not sure I could do that if my button was a ListView item

Comment: I asked you the XML which is in setContentView(R.layout.XML_NAME); iwant the **XML_NAME** content

Comment: Check my answer, we've faced the same issue (we use lots of listviews in our app), and that workaround is ugly but works

Comment: This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/43210947/4969047
See if it helps you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is an Android bug in my opinion, we just fix this issue doing this:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_to_hide"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         //Put here your views
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Just **hide LinearLayout with id LAYOUT_TO_HIDE** with `Visible.GONE` and then root FrameLayout will collapse its height giving you a "hidden" with non-blank-space header.

Comment: Hi there. Do you still have not found a better solution? Is this a bug really? I'm having the same problem

Comment: how is this still a problem in 2021

Comment: I am also facing this issue in 2021.. any update on this?

Comment: still facing this in 2023 :))))

Comment: Yes still facing issue. Have you find any solution

Answer (score 11):

set `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `0` where you want to hide item, by doing this

```
//if item's parent layout is LinearLayout, change according to your item xml
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0));
```

Answer (score 9):

All replies in this thread are suggesting a new wrapper view, which comes at a cost. The correct way of hiding a view completely is to set margins to 0 while setting visibility to *GONE*. In this code sample, *cardView* is the view I am trying to hide. The direct parent of *cardView* is RecyclerView, that's why we are using RecyclerView.LayoutParams - remember to replace with the right layout params.

```
if (cardView.getVisibility() != GONE) {
    cardView.setVisibility(GONE);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) cardView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: This is irrelevant for `ListView`.

Comment: @Miha_x64 Can you please explain why? ListView should behave the same as any other view.

Comment: The author of the question already tried `GONE` and then created this question. Another answer says that `GONE` doesn't work correctly inside `ListView`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20786397/3050249

Comment: My answer clearly states the additional step required since GONE is not enough. Your comment ignores the main part of my answer and the drawback associated with your linked answer.

Comment: Margins are not specified explicitly in the question. This means that they are `(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: If you have tried this solution and it did not work, let me know here. If you want to know why setting margins to 0 works, I don't know - perhaps it is/was a platform bug when the answer was written.

Comment: I prefer this way because it does not need to change the layout

Answer (score 4):

If this is stil needed, there is a great way to deal with it:

```
parentView.removeView(childView);
```

here an example:

```
final WhatEverLayout parentView, childView;
parentView = (WhatEverLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentView_xml);
childView =(WhatEverLayout)findViewById(R.id.childView_xml);
parentView.removeView(childView);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367587/visibility-of-gone-takes-still-space-of-particular-control-in-android?noredirect=1#comment48826130_30367587

Comment: All `addView` and `removeView` methods throw `UnsupportedOperationException` in `AdapterView`.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is set an if statement, whenever the condition to set the visibility to "GONE", set the view as wrap content and your space will be free, I did it and it worked for a seekbar

Comment: Please provide some example.

Comment: Let take my example for instance. I had to show a seek bar if the item was an audio file, if not, then no seekbar. So I set the seekbar in the xml as wrap content (height and width) meaning the layout will occupy the space of the showed element. And when the seekbar is "GONE", the space is not used since the view wrap a content that is not there. If I could I would have showed a screen capture but the trick is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution. Create a new layout file with name "special.xml", copy the code to the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

</LinearLayout>
```

Use condition to **inflate the empty layout** inside the newview. Don't Use the **view.setVisibility(View.GONE);**.

```
if(true){
  view=mInflater.inflate ( R.layout.special,parent, false );
}else{
  view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.normal,parent,false);
  // The view that you want to be visible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

header_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mHeaderView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mNoHelpLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="176dip"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
             />
       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater =(LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View outerView =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
mHeaderView = (LinearLayout) outerView.findViewById(R.id.mHeaderView);
```

use mHeaderView.setVisiable() to control visiable not the outerView.setVisiable().
it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
If you want to show itemView 

if (ItemBean.isShow()) 
{
   holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 } else
 {
     holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
     holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :
`viewToHide?.postDelayed({ viewToHide?.visibility = View.GONE }, durationInMillis)`

Comment: worked for me, tks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when using `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()`, in the `Layout Inspector tool` I see that the view is `Gone`, but it still taking space, I think it is bug in Android, a workaround is to execute the visibility block with `View.post(Runnable action)`

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked if I did the showing/hiding on the next run loop.

```
parentView.post { 
   childViewToHide.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to force the parent view to remeasure its own height after children visibility changed.
Try something like this :

```
parentView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```

in this case, parent view is a **LinearLayout**.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using an animation and in my anim, I had the flag

`android:fillAfter="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

    
    <alpha
        android:duration="150"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

This caused the view to be set as invisible even when it was being set to `GONE`.

After removing `android:fillAfter="true"` I had no more issues and the view was then properly being set to `GONE`.

Answer (score 0):

> **A generic and easy solution is to avoid all thuse heck of code:**

You need to add a **Container Layout or a Parent Layout** over your set of views that you want to hide. It can be anything like CardView or FrameLayout or etc.

Just it has to be a parent for that view that you want to hide. And you wont get all those white spaces. Coz it will consider the entire container to hide instead of considering individual views to HIDE thus, avoiding the white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Setting view padding and margins to 0 and then set view visibility to gone solved my problem.

Answer (score -5):

I don't think this is a bug.. Just use GONE to make the empty space disappear.
CSS does the same thing. Try `display: block` vs `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: OP actually *wants* the empty space to disappear, but GONE doesn't seem to work.

Comment: display is not an android attribute

Comment: Well... I was just using "display" as an example here and v.setVisibility(View.GONE) worked in my case - the same did disappear.