# Visibility of Gone takes still space of particular control in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout, visibility

I am using the LinearLayout and inside there's button I am making visibilty gone based on supported states. SupportedStatuses are true then making Button as Visible but SupprtedStatuse are false then making button as Gone.

This is in a header and Button is Gone but still takes up the space.
Here is the Layout which I am using.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llparentView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content
            android:orientation="vertical">
      <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_change_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Anybody have a good solution then it helps me a lot.

Comment: do you change the visibility programmatically ?

Comment: setVisibility to linear layout instead of button

Comment: yes.. changing the visibility programmatically .. @ Blackbelt

Comment: I can't setVisibilty to linear layout there are other controls as well..

Comment: I am on same screen and problem exists

Comment: Does removeView help me ? and how ?

Comment: Why do you need a linearlayout around your button?

Comment: It's my parentLayout there are other view such as Textviews etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302172/setvisibilitygone-view-becomes-invisible-but-still-occupies-space - UI point of view this problem currently facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setVisibility(GONE) view becomes invisible but still occupies space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302172/setvisibilitygone-view-becomes-invisible-but-still-occupies-space)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a FrameLayout around whatever layout you are using
For example:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- put your views here -->
</FrameLayout>
```

This will ensure when using `View.GONE` the FrameLayout collapses on the space.

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap your button in another Linear/Frame layout and change their visibility as well.