# setVisibility(View.GONE) leaves empty placeholder

Tags: android, visibility

I have this layout:

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/holder"
                    layout="@layout/live_result"/>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/stream_holder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="233dp">

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/stream"
                        android:layout_width="317dp"
                        android:layout_height="233dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/offer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

When holder view and stream holder view are shown periodically depending on state. Method setVisibility works fine on stream holder view, and it is appearing and disappearing properly. Problem is with included layout which is shown properly, but when I set visibility to GONE, it just leaves empty placeholder where it was. (It is gone but space is still there, just like if I called INIVSIBLE) Btw included layout is complex layout in which root hierarchy is LinearLayout.

Can anyone help me to configure this to hide this view?

Comment: try calling requestLayout() or invalidate() on the parent view

Comment: try adding visibity in the xml and changing it from the script. this way it works for me. also could you show the script that sets visibility?

Comment: nope, tried all that.

Comment: Try wrapping it up in another linear layout like this...                `<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/hide_layout"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         **//Put here include here**
    </LinearLayout>`                                                                               See if this works. Although I consider this as a quick dirty solution. Still try this first.

Comment: Tried that as well, but not working.

Comment: pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302172/setvisibilitygone-view-becomes-invisible-but-still-occupies-space