# Setting the View visibility to View.GONE, makes it invisible, still takes up space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a view that I want to collapse, so I set the visibility to View.GONE the view becomes invisible, but it still takes up space.

I don't know what it might be, someone has ideas?

Here is an image before (View D):
[image: Here is an image before]

Here is an image after (View D): 
[image]

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/mainColor"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:fillViewport="false"
android:scrollbars="none">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/options_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <!-- other irrelevants views -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/toolbar_options_title_time"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/option_hexa_sorting" />

    <com.development.mekanius.bounce.customElements.HexaRadioGroupView
        android:id="@+id/option_hexa_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/time_title" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/option_create_post"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/option_hexa_time" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which view are you trying to hide? It's unclear in the XML.

Comment: Have you done view GONE or INVISIBLE?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302172/setvisibilitygone-view-becomes-invisible-but-still-occupies-space

Comment: Sorry. The view I'm trying to hide is option_hexa_time, I'm using View.GONE

Comment: I've already tried wrapping the view in a LinearLayout but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: the empty space is not coming from view it is probably due to android:layout_marginTop="32dp"

Comment: What do you mean? it looks more than 32dp... And when I set the view in the layout editor it works, it doesn't work programmatically.

Comment: Try this: `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` on view D or E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, sorry for the late reply, but I have been stuck on finals and I didn't have much time.

Ok, the problem was a whole other story.
I'm using Spotify's Mobius as a state machine:
https://github.com/spotify/mobius

It's using a background thread to consume effects, and so acting on the UI gives an error. But for some reason the error was suppressed (was not on the logs and did't throw an exception), so I was seeing simply the view not obeying commands.

I came to this conclusion removing code lines until something worked.
Very old fashion.

Thanks for all that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours debugging why this was happening to me and stumbled upon your answer. I was mutating visibility from an Rx-Java thread that was supposed to be operating on the main thread but apparently not! Doing a view.post {..} solved the issue for me! Thanks so much