# Screen goes blank for the Translation Animation section

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to display a view under the Bottom Navigation Bar to show a message to the user.

- This view needs to be hidden with a Translation Animation.

The current behaviour without an animation looks as per the attachment below

[image: behaviour without animation]

When performing the animation, the section covered by the Translation Animation is then removed from the screen and leaves a blank space (which I cannot get rid of it):

[image: behaviour with animation]

Here is the code for the Animation:

```
public void hideGlobalAppMessage(){
    //Animation that hides the green message down
    globalMessageContainer.animate()
            .translationY(globalMessageContainer.getHeight())
            .setDuration(500);

    //Animation that moves the bottom navigation bar down
    navBar.animate()
            .translationY(globalMessageContainer.getHeight())
            .setDuration(500);
}
```

Is there any alternate way to perform this animation without getting this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your XML codes for this page. What's your root layout constraint, linear or relative if constraint layout maybe you didn't constraint recyclerview bottom point.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction, I thought it was an Animation issue but as you said it was related to my layout.xml. I had several items positioned under a Linear Layout and once one of the child views was getting hidden it was leaving that blank space. I found the solution under this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302172/setvisibilitygone-view-becomes-invisible-but-still-occupies-space